# Is it biologically feasible for a humanoid species to have both types of germ cells?

Tags: humanoid, reproduction, sex

I thought up a race of humanoids called Daemons for a Homestuck-inspired video game/webcomic. I won’t go into a ton of detail about them, though if I wanted to, I could fill up nine whole questions. Their most distinctive trait are their odd reproductive abilities.

And “odd” is definitely understating it. So, to start off, Daemons hatch from eggs.  Demons are hermaphrodite producing both sperm and egg cells, and self-fertilization can occur.

As far as I know, no organism on Earth can do this. So here’s my question: **is the presence of sperm and egg cells in Daemons possible/feasible?**

More clarification can be provided if necessary.

Comment: This species is neither male nor female, but hermaphroditic. Many plants are, some animals are (earthworms come to mind). Being humanoid morphologically doesn't preclude this, though they probably couldn't arise in an Earth like our own. Plausible and valid for a fantasy setting. Probably looking at a different genetic mechanism too other than XX/XY chromosomes. As for genitalia, you've got that all screwed up... these things are likely to just have cloacas.

Comment: An interesting real-life parallel from the lizard world: [Aspidoscelis uniparens](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Desert_grassland_whiptail_lizard&oldid=1149364418). Instead of having two distinct sets of gametes, they are triploid, having three copies of the chromosomes instead of two.

Comment: Without requiring you to go into the gory details, the requisite plumbing makes it seem a little unlikely (or at least, impractical) to have some members of the species with "male" genetalia and some with "female"...

Comment: By definition that isn't a binary gendered species. It's hermaphroditic.

Comment: So from what I’m seeing, I should remove the part about males and females having different genitalia and replace it with a) Daemons possess both types of sex organs or b) Daemons have cloaca.

Comment: Another option is that they work like Flatworms.  They only have penises and they inseminate each other by stabbing another daemon with thier penises and a female organ forms around the wound to accept the impregnation.

Comment: @Nosajimiki That definitely sounds demonic...

Comment: I don't do this very often but VTC:Needs More Focus because you are allowed to ask one and only one question (you're asking two) and -1 because it's one thing to ask us for help rationalizing the existence of a fictional creation and quite another to ask if it's possible (as in, "can it exist in real life?") the answer to which is *obviously* no. We don't help people extend the real world, per the [help/on-topic] we help people build imaginary worlds. In your imaginary world, the answer is just as obviously always "yes."

Comment: I must say I can't really understand why this question has (so far) garnered 6 downvotes but only two close votes. It isn't a great question, but a score of -6 seems a little harsh.

Answer (score 3):

### Either Sequential Hermaphrodites or Hermaphroditic Polymorphs

Hermaphroditic animals are those that have both genders. Many kinds of worms, fish, arthropods, and plants are Hermaphroditic.

Hermaphrodites are not male or female, per say but there are Sequential Hermaphrodites who change what gender they present based on environmental or developmental factors.  So, if your demons all look like "men", and then transform into "women" when they are ready to carry babies, they would be a Sequential Hermaphrodite.

That said, if thier two different forms are not related to reproduction, then int might be more appropriate to call theme Hermaphroditic Polymorphs.  A polymorph is an animal that has multiple physical forms within a single gender.  Ants for example form very different looking worker/warrior/queen ants that are all suited to specific purposes in the colony.  So, if the "female" demons had bodies that made them especially good at one thing and the "male" demons, something else, but they were both equally capable of sexual reproduction, then they would be Polymorphs.

### Humans Could be are the Evolutionary Pressure

Polymorphs typically evolve as a response to frequency dependent selection.  This is where one form is more desirable in one niche, but another form is more desirable in another, and the animals niche is forced to sometimes change very quickly based on uncontrollable environmental factors.

Humans can be this environmental pressure.  Humans hate deamons.  Always going to war and trying to wipe them out.  The male form deamons are bigger and stronger so they are better at protecting the colony from human extermination. So, in cases where deamons have the upper-hand, they produce more warrior forms (males), but when the war starts to go badly, survival often becomes more a matter of sympathy than brute force.  The Female forms are made to be as sexy as possible to human warriors; so, when humans do over-run a deamon hive, they have a tendency to kill all the male form deamons and rape, drive off, or enslave the female forms.

So, while the battle may be lost, the female form has a much higher chance of surviving and going on to form a new colony due to humans being less willing to kill them.